# wordpress media upload doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, upload, image-uploading

My wordpress media upload doesn't work, something it is a white screen, other only some words.

Here some images about it:

[image]

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: What do you see in your browser console? This seems like a JS error.

Comment: I dont see nothing, only: "The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating"but isnt this issue

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried deactivating the plugins one by one. And check  the issue. Most probably its plugin conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Disabling plugin one-by-one helped me (it was "SocialGrid" plugin, which conflicted with wordpress media upload panel).

Also, try to add

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

to wp-config.php just before

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

In some cases, it might help.